# Assignment as an argument

Tags: javascript

I came across some syntax I haven't seen before here: http://appendto.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/

```
(function( skillet, $, undefined ) {
  //Private Property
  var amountOfGrease = "1 Cup";
  //Public Method
  skillet.toString = function() {
    console.log( skillet.quantity + ' ' +
                 skillet.ingredient + ' & ' +
                 amountOfGrease + ' of Grease' );
    console.log( isHot ? 'Hot' : 'Cold' );
  };
}( window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery ));
```

I understand that the author is checking the global scope for a `skillet` object, and passing it into the IIFE if it exists, I'm just a bit unclear as to the value of passing `window.skillet = window.skillet` is.

Assignments evaluate to the value of the assignment:

```
var x = 1;
var y = x = x;
console.log(y); //1
console.log(y = (x = x)); true
```

But since `window.skillet` would be falsey if it is undefined, why wouldn't the author simply pass this:

```
( window.skillet || {}, jQuery )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It guarantees that window.skillet is defined after this line of code is executed. If it was undefined before, it will now contain an empty object.

It's a shorter version of:

```
window.skillet = window.skillet || {};

(function( skillet, $, undefined ) {
      //...
  };
}( window.skillet, jQuery ));

// at this point window.skillet is guaranteed to be defined
```

Using expressions that contain assignments is not a good idea if you want your code to be readable, but it can make your code significantly shorter.

Comment: And why wouldn't `( window.skillet || {}, jQuery )` accomplish the same thing? Why, specifically, the assignment in the argument?

Comment: window.skillet will remain unchanged if the assignment is not there

Answer (score 1):

The way the author did it will ensure that `window.skillet` is no longer `undefined`, if it was in the first place. Then, that value is passed in. The way you suggested will end up passing in the same value, however `window.skillet` will still be undefined.

The author could have done the following to make it more readable:

```
// preceding code....
    if(!window.skillet) {
        window.skillet = {};
    }
}( window.skillet, jQuery ));
```